# Clear log every 7 days

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j, logback

I am using slf4j with scala. Is there a way to rotate logs?

I am trying to clear the log every 7 days. Or in other words, empty out the log file every 7 days.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with Scala.  On the other hand, it does depend greatly on what back-end you're using with slf4j - java.util.logging, logback, log4j, or whatever.

Comment: Good point - it can be dealt with at the app level

Comment: If you are using log4j as a back end for slf4j, see [the appenders doc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

Comment: My previous comment was for log4j 2.*.  If log4j 1.*, consider [DailyRollingFileAppender](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender)

Comment: slf4j is just an interface. It's a different answer according to your chosen implementation/backend (which should really be Logback if you have any choice in the matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender` add the following rolling policy:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <!-- daily rollover -->
    <fileNamePattern>logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    <!-- keep 7 days' worth of history -->
    <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```

No need for any external solutions, logback will take care of your logging history for you. For this and other information, the [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/) is always a good source.

Answer (score 2):

For linux - logrotate is a popular solution

Add your log rotation config to the following directory:

```
/etc/logrotate.d/

/var/log/your.log {
  missingok
  notifempty
  size 30k
  weekly
  create 0600 root root
}
```

Comment: I am using Windows. Is there a way to do this in windows? I am using logback.core.fileAppender